# Selecting matching subset in many-to-many relation

Tags: sql, postgresql

Suppose I have a many-to-many relation between users and projects: one user may belong to several projects and one project may have multiple users.  This relation is encoded in table `user_projects`:

```
create table user_projects
(
proj_id int references projs(id) not null,
user_id int references users(id) not null,
primary key (proj_id, user_id)
);
```

Here's my problem: given a set of users (user1, user2, ...), I want to select all projects for which the given set of users is a subset of all its users.

If, for example, I were insert the data below and then ask for all projects with users 1 and 2, then the query should return only project 1.

```
insert into user_projects values (1, 1);
insert into user_projects values (1, 2);
insert into user_projects values (1, 3);
insert into user_projects values (2, 1);
insert into user_projects values (2, 3);
```

(I'm using PostgreSQL, if the best solution happens to be non-standard.)

**EDIT:** For clarification, the set of users should be interpreted as a constraint on the list of projects to return.  The set {u1, u2} means that the list of projects should include only those projects having at least users u1 and u2; the set {u1} means that all projects having at least user u1 should be returned, and as a limiting case, the empty set means that **all** projects should be returned.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Select project_ID 
from user_projects
where user_ID in (1,2)
group by project_ID
Having count(*) = 2
```

You know that you have 2 users, you know that they will be unique (primary key)
so you know that if there are 2 records, for the same project then it's one you want.

Your question indicated you have a GIVEN sent of users therefor you know what users and how many there are.  the above SQL could be updated to accept parameters for these known and thus remains dynamic, not limited to just 2 users.

```
where user_ID in (userlist)
having count(*) = (cntuserList)
```

-----------To handle situation when set of users is empty-----

```
Select P.project_ID 
from Projects P
LEFT JOIN user_projects UP
where (UP.user_ID in (1,2) OR UP.USER_ID is null)
group by project_ID
Having count(*) = 2
```

So here's what this does.  It returns all projects and if there's a user affiliated to that project it identifies them.
If you set contains users, the list of projects returned is filtered by that set ensuring that the entire set is in the project through the having clause.

If the set is empty, the LEFT join along with the userID is null statement will keep the projects with no users listed regardless of if the set is empty or not.  The having clause will further reduce the set to the # of users you defined in the set, OR 0 indicating return all projects with no users assigned.

One additional edge case we didn't discuss yet is what should happen if a project contains more users than what you defined in the set.  Presently this project would be returned; but i'm not positive that's what you wanted.

on a side note thanks for making me think.  I don't get to get into the code as much anymore; which is why I troll here from time to time to see if I can help!

Comment: I like this approach!  One little problem though: it does not handle gracefully the limit case where the set of users is empty.  I realise the SQL standard is partly to blame, since set expressions cannot be empty.  Still, it would be nice to handle that corner case as well without resorting to extra logic.

Comment: Check to make sure you don't have an empty set before calling the SP/Function.  if your count <= 0 in your set, then don't call procedure, you know that no projects will match..  THe limit case, user_projects will not contain a project without any users right?  So if there is an empty set, no projects would be returned... or do you want to see the projects with no users if no users are specified?  if so that requires an additional join.  But this requirement was a bit unclear in the question :D

Comment: Yeah, I was a bit unclear as to the actual meaning of the "set of users".  In reality it should be interpreted as a constraint on the list of projects.  Thus, when I query all projects with user set (user1, user2) this means "give me all projects that satisfy the constraint of having all users in this set".  Therefore, the empty set limit should translate into "give me all projects, period".  And yes, I know this can be done with extra logic; still I think the hallmark of a really good solution is when corner cases are handled automatically without requiring extra logic...

Comment: I think I can handle it in the above I just didn't know it was what your after.

Comment: For clarification: @Jon: Did empty set mean you give no users (thus, `(1,2)` above would formally be `()`, or did you mean projects that have no user assigned to them? In the first case, I believe @xQbert's solution not to succeed. Furthermore, the correctness of the less general solution still requires the primary key (or unique constraint) to be set - in my experience it is dangerous to rely on such boundary conditions, as they might change without remembering to adapt that particular query. I believe my solution should also handle the boundary case, if I understand it the right way.

Comment: @Thilo: I've added a clarification to the original question.

Comment: @xQbert I have similar requirement but I need only those project in which have only user1 or only user2 or both (user1 and user2).
if some projects have users (user1 , user4 ),(user2 , user4 ) we will not take those.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2263675/selecting-against-subsets-of-a-list-in-mysql

Comment: @Ashu stack works on each question being it's own unique response.  It would help to have a new question with specific table structure and expected results.  I would point back to this and your linked questions as close to what you need. but define your own problem so it has it's own answer (unless the aforementioned actually is the answer)

Comment: @xQbert , Thank you. But i found the solution and posted it in the comment but thank you for you reply :) .

Answer (score 2):

Here is one more solution, seemingly more straightforward:

```
select  proj_id
from    user_projects
group by proj_id
having  array_agg ( user_id ) @> array [1, 2]
```

---

As @Thilo noticed, there can be projects with no users assigned to them. Therefore in case when input set with users is empty, the query should return all the projects from the projs table. Here is the improved solution:

```
select      p.proj_id
from        projs           p
left join   user_projects   up
    on      p.proj_id = up.proj_id
group by    p.proj_id
having      array_agg ( up.user_id ) @> array (
    select  u
    from    generate_series ( 1, 2 )
    where   false   /* an empty set */
    )
;
```

---

I have been testing for a while the performance of the rated solutions. As far as there was no significant differences when querying small data sets (1 670 rows in user_projects), another case was when table user_projects had 1 667 000 rows
(columns proj_id and user_id have been filled with random values from 1 to 1 000 000; on average 2 users and maximum 11 users in one project):

- array_agg method (reading from projs and user_projects) required usually 24 sec (sometimes less) to give result.
- Wildplasser's approach: always 31 sec.
- Thilo's query took too long, I decided to cancel it.
- xQbert's "count" method, relying strongly on indexes, was many times faster - took almost always **only 0.5 sec**. It would need to be rewritten, though, in order to handle empty input set of users.

[Tests were run on Postgresql 9.2.2 on a not newest PC, although on Postgresql 8.4 on a newer PC the proportions were similar].

Comment: This is great!  Your initial solution suffices, actually, since the limit case of the empty user set should result in returning all projects.

Comment: Using `array_agg` in fact is a clever idea. +1 !

Answer (score 2):

This kind of relational division can often be expressed in terms of `SELECT FROM a WHERE NOT EXISTS ( b WHERE NOT EXISTS (c))`

```
WITH users AS (
        SELECT generate_series (1,2)::integer AS user_id
        )
SELECT DISTINCT up.proj_id
FROM user_projects up
   -- all the projects, but
   -- NOT the ones that miss (at least) one of the users
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM users us
          -- The projects that miss (at least) one of the users
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (
                SELECT *
                FROM user_projects nx
                WHERE nx.user_id = us.user_id AND nx.proj_id = up.proj_id
                )
        )
        ;
```

Answer (score 1):

A more general answer that allows you to have arbitrary user sets with the same amount of code. First, we create a table with the user set:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE user_set ( 
  u int
);
INSERT INTO user_set VALUES (1), (2);
```

You could replace this table by any function that you may put in the `FROM` clause below.

Now select the actual projects:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    proj_id 
FROM 
    user_projects 
WHERE 
    true = ALL (
        -- Select all required users and test if they are a member of the project
        SELECT u IN (
            -- Select all user ids of this project
            SELECT 
                user_id 
            FROM 
                user_projects AS up 
            WHERE 
                up.proj_id = user_projects.proj_id
        )
        FROM 
            user_set
   )
```

And the [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/afb0b/6).

Comment: Seems to work with simple examples, though it's quite convoluted.  I'm a bit confused with the "true = ALL" bit.  Wouldn't just ALL suffice?

Comment: @Jon Just using `ALL (subselect)` sadly is no valid SQL. The syntax for `ALL` is `value <operator> ALL (subselect)`, that's the reason for this non-intuitive statement. See http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/functions-subquery.html. (Note that @wildplasser's answer is more or less a negation of mine.)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
SELECT u.proj_id
FROM user_projects u
   JOIN user_projects u2 on u.proj_id = u2.proj_id
WHERE u.user_id = 1 and u2.user_id = 2
```

And here is the [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/754ce/6).

Good luck.

Comment: I may be missing something, but how would you handle the case where the set contains N users?

Answer (score 0):

You could use several JOIN blocks, for example:

```
 SELECT Up1.project_id
   FROM user_projects as up1
   JOIN user_projects as up2 on up1.project_id=up2.project_id
  WHERE up1.user_id=1
    AND up2.user_id=2;
```

You should create a new JOIN block for every userin your desired set.

Comment: I may be missing something, but how would you handle the case where the set contains N users? (N is not known before hand, of course, and I cannot meta-program the SQL statement)