# Query where a post has tags, which needs to be in every category

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord, rails-postgresql

I have a post which can have tags and a tag has a category. Now I need to create a scope of "published". A post can only be published if it has tags in every available category. So in other words. If the database contains 4 tagcategory records, a post should have tags in all those 4 categories, to be considered published.

A Post has many tags (through tag_categories). And tag belongs to a tag_category. A tagcategory has many tags

On a post instance, I could easily create such method:

```
def has_tags_in_all_categories?
  #select all category id's
  category_ids = TagCategory.pluck(:id)
  #select all post tag id's
  tag_ids = self.tags.pluck(:tag_category_id)
  #create a new array with the category ids from the post.tags subtracted from all category ids
  remaining = category_ids.reject{|x| tag_ids.include? x}
  #if id's are left in the array -> Not all categories are filled in.
  remaining.empty?
end
```

But to display all published posts on a single page, I need to create a scope. Looping through all posts and applying this method, obviously would be result in lot's of unnessesary database queries.

Could anyone help me out with the query?

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    def self.published
      find(:all) #No clue here
    end
end
```

database (sorry I dont know how to make this fancy):

```
posts
    id
    title

posts_tags
    post_id
    tag_id

tags
    id
    tag_category_id
    name

tag_categories
    id
    name
```

Comment: The standard trick to do this in SQL is by means of a `NOT EXISTS ( NOT EXISTS(..)` construct. BTW: adding some relevant DDL would help.

Comment: See my answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/14538671/905902